# How to remove the error "Object is not subscriptable" in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python coding and scraping.
I want to scrape the reviews of a hotel and the rating count for each review. 
I am getting object not subscriptable error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib.request

altarray = ""
count=0;
review_list=[]

        line = review.get_text()


            review_list.append(line)
            print(line)

        else:
            print("nothing found")
    for rating in soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "rating reviewItemInline"}):
        alt = rating.find('img', alt=True)
        if alt is not None:

           if alt[-5:] == 'stars':
              if len(altarray) == 0:
                     altarray = [alt]
             else:
                     altarray.append(alt) 
                     Rating = altarray[x][:1]
                     print(Rating)
        else:
           print("No rating!)
```

Comment: Have you tried searching this site for `NoneType object is not subscriptable` before asking this question?  I get 140 questions when I submit that query.

Comment: Yes I did alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.find` method could return `None`, so you should apply None check to the result of `rating.find('img', alt=True)`.

```
alt = rating.find('img', alt=True)
if alt is not None:
    # Do something
```

Comment: @MinjaNinja It means that there's no `img` under `rating`.

Comment: So how can I implement that?

Comment: @MinjaNinja Update your current code to the question.

Comment: Can you guide how to get the bubble rating and display its count?

Comment: I implemented your suggested piece of code again and fund i missed something before.. Now its giving an output "No rating!"

Comment: @MinjaNinja You mean the `bubble_40` class?

Comment: @MinjaNinja Actually, there's NO `img` tag in `rating`.

Comment: I want to count the bubbles appearing as reviewer's rating in the form of numbers

Comment: So how can I access those bubbles if there's no img tag?

Comment: @MinjaNinja you can access the span by using `rating.find('span', class_='ui_bubble_rating')`.

Comment: Its still giving the same output "No rating!" which means it still doesnt have accessed the rating

Comment: @MinjaNinja It works here. Which line did the exception raise from?